# CMake : How to change default package name using CPack - linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, package, cpack

In my project, I have created two package.

1. Default package with all the components except 'XYZ' module.
2. Specific package with XYZ component by using `COMPONENT <XYZ>` in `INSTALL` command.

Now, problem is that, I have specify `CPACK_SOURCE_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` and when I run `make package` command its generated two package with name as specify bellow.

`set(CPACK_SOURCE_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "AB-1.0.2")` in CMakeList.txt

```
make package
```

then otput are:

```
CPack: Create package
CPack: - package: /home/build/AB/AB-1.0.2-Unspecified.tar.bz2 generated.
CPack: - package: /home/build/AB/AB-1.0.2-XYZ.tar.bz2 generated.
```

I want to change that default package name as well as second package name.

I have googled but unable to find any direct way to specify default package name or rename this package.

Many thaks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file name with the `CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` variable
`CPACK_SOURCE_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` gets only involved when you run

```
make package_source
```

EDIT

You have also the option to change the default Component name with setting the CMAKE variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_DEFAULT_COMPONENT_NAME`

Have a look at this http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html

Comment: Thanks for reply... When I use `CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` variable then that value is treated as prefix name. i.e. Same as `CPACK_SOURCE_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` variable. I have also tried that option.

Comment: Could you please post your full CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: with CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME variable, we are loosing the package version